# Why does MongoDB/Mongoose find query with null or undefined argument return all docs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

API requests same data from MongoDB with specific parameters. But I don't want to return any docs If query parameter are null or undefined. On the contrary, MongoDB returns **all docs**. Why and is this normal?

```
await exampleModel.find({}).lean().exec()        // return all docs. That's okay.
await exampleModel.find(null).lean().exec()      // return all docs. That's weird.
await exampleModel.find(undefined).lean().exec() // return all docs. That's weird.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [this is normal](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html). Perhaps MongoDB defaults to an empty filter (`{}`) when passing `null` or `undefined` or not passing a parameter at all (`foo.find()`). In any case the `filter` and the `projection` (the second parameter) are optional:

> `query`: *Specifies selection filter using query operators. To return all documents in a collection, omit this parameter or pass an empty document ({}).*
>
> `projection`: *Specifies the fields to return in the documents that match the query filter. To return all fields in the matching documents, omit this parameter.*

If you want to not return anything if the query is null or undefined you can build it like this:

```
const results = query ? await exampleModel.find(query).lean.exec() : []
```

Comment: I'd like to add something if you permit me, the thing is both parameters are optional (undefined, false, 0, null will be passed as if you did'nt pass any parameter), reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html

Comment: @JoseVasquez Thanks! I included that in the answer now.