# find database user by any field passed in params

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

I am trying to find users in database based on any of three fields.
in postman I have the following paths

`http://localhost:8082/api/users/617473029f80eda3643a7fdd`

`http://localhost:8082/api/users/Michael`

`http://localhost:8082/api/users/25`

currently in my database I have all those values for different users. So the idea is that path1 returns the user with that id, path2 returns the user with that name, and path3 user with that age. fyi: I am testing this out so as of now those field values are unique and there are no repeats in database fields.

with the following code, the only thing that returns is when I pass in the id, but the entire database returns. Nothing returns when I pass in name or age

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
  User.find( { $or: [
    {"_id": req.params.id},
    {"name": req.params.name},
    {"age": req.params.age}
    ]})
  .then(user => res.json(user))
  .catch(err => res.status(404).json({nouserfound: '***NoUserFound***'}))
});
```

Thanks!

EDIT: The following worked for me

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {

  User.find({$or: [
    {name: req.params.id},
    {age: req.params.id}
  ]})
  .then(user => res.json(user))
  .catch(err => res.status(404).json({nouserfound: '*** No User Found ***'}));
  
});
```

Only problem is that it does not catch the error, so while testing in postman anything that I send in that isn't a match just returns an empty array instead of the err. Not sure how this will affect the program itself or if it's ok

Answer (score 1):

`req.params.name` or `req.params.age` will be undefined because the route parameter is `req.params.id`. To get it working correctly, you'll have to look for the value by this route parameter only. The field names change, but the value - `req.params.id` remains same.

```
User.find( { $or: [
    {"_id": req.params.id},
    {"name": req.params.id},
    {"age": req.params.id}
    ]})
.then(user => res.json(user))
.catch(err => res.status(404).json({nouserfound: '***NoUserFound***'}))
```

Optionally: For future usage, rename `id` to `slug` would be a better option as this goes well with all other fields on your schema.

Comment: Wait! This makes perfect sense! Lemme try and report back

Answer (score 0):

This is how mongodb returns the results when you pass `undefined/null` which it treats as `find({})`.

You need to make a check if `name`/`age` exists. I am pretty sure this route won't use name/age, but uses `_id` only, so why don't you only pass `_id`;

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {

  // check what is available in req.params - name/age/id 
  // based on it create query and run it
  User.find({"_id": req.params.id})
  .then(user => res.json(user))
  .catch(err => res.status(404).json({nouserfound: '***NoUserFound***'}))
});
```

You should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59246925/why-does-mongodb-mongoose-find-query-with-null-or-undefined-argument-return-all) link.

Comment: I played around with this quite a bit and one thing I did is User.find("name":req.params.name or "age" : req.param.age)...... and it returned the user object, so I figured there could be a way to do all three

Comment: Have you checked the link? You can build a query based on what you received from the req object. If it is name pass filter as name and so on. It is simply to check what filter you need to add. I suggest you to check the link I shared.

Comment: ok I will check it out and report back if I found an answer

Comment: The question that you aksed why does it retun all the documents is due to undefined/null passed in the filter. This is how MONGO behaves when you pass undefined, null or empty object.

Comment: funny tho, when I console.log(req.params.id) its not null and it still behaves the same way

Comment: please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a different names for each request param, so the
`req.params.id` must be just an id, and won't be available via the name `req.params.name`

Try to send the request filed via query params, might make it easier.
I'd keep the `:id` endpoint, just a common way to request one user by id,
and create another endpoint for all the other requests.

Comment: tried doing this but it goes to the first one it finds (???) that's how it seemed anyway

Comment: Mongo DB have the `find({})` method for query few documents, and the `findOne({})` for just one document.

By the way, _id property should be unique and auto-generate by mongo inside `ObjectId` object

Comment: yep, it is, oh I should mention I am only testing the _id just to see how things work. Actually lemme try doing it without the "_id"

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you've specified `'/:id'` as the endpoint. Therefore, this will work but the rest won't work. To solve this, you need to create separate route for each request, not combining them in one.

```js
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
  User.find({"_id": req.params.id})
  .then(user => res.json(user))
  .catch(err => res.status(404).json({nouserfound: '***NoUserFound***'}))
});

router.get('/name', (req, res) => {
  User.find({"name": req.params.name})
  .then(user => res.json(user))
  .catch(err => res.status(404).json({nouserfound: '***NoUserFound***'}))
});

router.get('/age', (req, res) => {
  User.find({"age": req.params.age})
  .then(user => res.json(user))
  .catch(err => res.status(404).json({nouserfound: '***NoUserFound***'}))
});
```

Comment: I tried this and no matter what I passed in it went to the first one, reason I know is because I put unique messages for each get call. No matter what I passed in, name, id, or age it always sent the first message